# How to implement Google reCaptcha in an MVC3 application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, recaptcha

Can anyone explain how to have reCaptcha functionality like stackoverflow in my MVC3 application.

And how can you customize that?

Comment: Recaptcha? http://www.google.com/recaptcha

Comment: I would recommend using a Honeypot ReCaptcha. The experience for your users is MUCH better. There is one fore ASP.NET MVC here http://nuget.org/packages/SimpleHoneypot.MVC

Comment: @Paul, Do you have example of how to implement honeypot?

Comment: @updev There is an example here: https://github.com/webadvanced/Honeypot-MVC/wiki Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: NuGet **Google reCAPTCHA V2** for MVC 4 and 5

- [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/reCAPTCH.MVC/)
- [Demo And Document](http://recaptchamvc.apphb.com/)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I use the Google ReCaptcha and it works very well and is very simple to implement.

**Note that if you are using Https be sure you have the current version of the dll (1.0.5.0 at this time)**

You need to create an account on the Google Recaptcha site and get a set of public and private keys. Add the keys to your web project main web.config file:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="ReCaptchaPrivateKey" value="put your private key value here" />
    <add key="ReCaptchaPublicKey" value="put your public key value here" />
</appSettings>
```

Now use NuGet and install the reCAPTCHA plugin for .NET

Then, go to your web.config file inside of your VIEWS folder. Add this line:

```
<namespaces>
  <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
  <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
  <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
  <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
  <add namespace="Recaptcha"/>
</namespaces>
```

Then, in your view that you want to show the captcha, add the using statement at the top of your file

```
@using Recaptcha;
```

then add this to your view:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    Are you a human?
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.Raw(Html.GenerateCaptcha("captcha", "clean"))
    @Html.ValidationMessage("captcha")
</div>
```

In your controller action you will need to modify the signature to accept the captcha results:

```
[HttpPost]
[RecaptchaControlMvc.CaptchaValidator]
public ActionResult ForgotPassword(CheckUsernameViewModel model, bool captchaValid, string captchaErrorMessage) {
    if (!Membership.EnablePasswordReset)
        throw new Exception("Password reset is not allowed\r\n");
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
        if(captchaValid) {
            return RedirectToAction("AnswerSecurityQuestion", new { username = model.Username });
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError("", captchaErrorMessage);
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Following those steps have allowed me to implement captcha on several pages and it works smoothly. Note that the parameter names on the controller action MUST BE NAMED CORRECTLY:

```
bool captchaValid, string captchaErrorMessage
```

If you changed these parameter names you WILL get an error at runtime when your form posts back to the controller action.

Comment: What is the public/private key value? What should I put there?

Comment: @updev - you get that by signing up for them on Google's ReCaptcha page: http://www.google.com/recaptcha/

Comment: @cd-smith: I got a strange behavior when following your guidelines to add Recaptcha to a MVC4 project ; the controller action get called twice when I submit the form, first with the correct Recaptcha results, and then a second time with error results! Did you face anything similar?

Comment: @ThomasWeiss No, I'm sorry I never had anything like that happen. But it sounds like a familiar situation. Are you posting via Ajax?

Comment: @cd-smith Thanks for your reply. No it's not Ajax so it's not a bind/unbind issue. And it only happens once the RecaptchaControlMvc.CaptchaValidator attribute is applied to the action... I'll have a deeper look with Fiddler to see if the second call to the action actually comes from the browser or is something internal. Will let you know!

Comment: @cd-smith So it seems that my issue is absolutely not related to the Recatpcha, it's really something similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779410/controller-actions-hit-multiple-times-asp-net-mvc-4-app-running-in-azure-emula Thanks again.

Comment: i'm trying to implement this, my form is submited using jQuery $.ajax and the validation is responding always false even though the recaptcha_response_field has the correct answer. any help?

Comment: @FabioG You might want to post a question with your specific code so we can see exactly what you are trying to do and can help you out faster.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using a Honeypot Captcha. The experience for your users is MUCH better. There is one fore ASP.NET MVC here http://nuget.org/packages/SimpleHoneypot.MVC

```
PM> Install-Package SimpleHoneypot.MVC4
```

There is a WiKi on how to get it up here: https://github.com/webadvanced/Honeypot-MVC/wiki
Just start out with the `Getting Started` section.

You can read more about the general idea of a Honeypot Captcha here: http://haacked.com/archive/2007/09/11/honeypot-captcha.aspx