# asp.net mvc 3 razor and reCaptcha errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, recaptcha

I want to use reCaptcha control in my asp.net mvc 3 razor view engine c# project

I found this tutorial

http://thenullreference.com/blog/robots-gotcha-down-get-recaptcha-in-asp-net-mvc/

I copied codes from there but visual studio gives error on this `private IHttpForm httpForm;`

Does anybody have a idea how i can solve this problem?

Comment: HttpForm class is something the author implemented himself. You'll need to work around those calls in order to achieve the same functionality.

Comment: NuGet **Google reCAPTCHA V2** for MVC 4 and 5

- [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/reCAPTCH.MVC/)
- [Demo And Document](http://recaptchamvc.apphb.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my walkthrough for implementing Google reCaptcha.

It shows all the steps necessary to add reCaptcha to your site.

[How to implement Google reCaptcha in an MVC3 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740402/how-to-implement-google-recaptcha-in-an-mvc3-application/9740583#9740583)