# reCAPTCHA MVC3 problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, recaptcha

I have tried almost everything, but cant make it work.

I can use the dll in my controller but cant render in view.

```
 [RecaptchaControlMvc.CaptchaValidator]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
```

I dont have an   @ReCaptcha.GetHtml(theme: "red") option in my Razor View, only http://prntscr.com/9agkf

I have this code in my Razor View

```
 @Html.GenerateCaptcha()
```

Any finally looks what i get [Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/9agl2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer here 
[How to implement Google reCaptcha in an MVC3 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740402/how-to-have-captcha-functionality-like-stackoverflow-in-my-mvc3-application/9740583#9740583)

It details the needs to properly generate reCaptcha in MVC 3