# no recaptcha.getHTML function available

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on asp.net MVC 3 form. I made sure to have the recaptcha.dll,system.web.helpers dll, Webmatrix.Data.dll, Webmatrix.Webdata.dll in my project references, and I made sure to add the @using System.Web.Helpers statement at the top of my form view.

However, when I type @Recaptcha, there is no getHTML method available, only Design, RecaptchaControl,RecaptchaControlMVC,RecaptchaResponse,and RecaptchaValidator. What else do I need to do to use Recaptcha?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you also add this to the top of your View?

```
@using Recaptcha;
```

To generate the reCaptcha in the view use:

```
@Html.Raw(Html.GenerateCaptcha("captcha", "clean"))
```

Also see here if you need to verify that everything is in place

[How to implement Google reCaptcha in an MVC3 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740402/how-to-have-captcha-functionality-like-stackoverflow-in-my-mvc3-application/9740583#9740583)

Answer (score 0):

You need "Microsoft.Web.Helpers.dll" not "System.Web.Helpers.dll"