# recaptcha.validate method unavailable in mvc3 controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I'm writing an mvc3 form with a recaptcha field.

At the top of my controller, I make sure to have:
@using System.Web.Helpers
@using Recaptcha

and the recaptcha field is rendered on the view when it's called, but it doesn't have any bearing on if the page is considered valid.
In the view, I render it with @ReCaptcha.GetHtml(publicKey: "[public removed from this example]")

I tried to call Recaptcha.Validate in my controller but then I'm told it doesn't exist in the current context. When I use intellisense on Recaptcha, the only fields available are Design, RecaptchaControl, RecaptchaControlMVC, RecaptchaResponse, and RecaptchaValidator. Why doesn't my recaptcha field work and why is the validate function non-existent according to visual studio?

Comment: Check out this article: http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/12/02/using-recaptcha-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx
Regarding intellisense: I guess Recapcha is the namespace, hence you see the classes in it. In the mentioned article he uses the RecapchaValidator class to validate the request.

Comment: See this walkthrough http://stackoverflow.com/a/9740583/816602