# Adding google recaptcha server side verification MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I've been following the google recaptcha instructions and am at the point where I want to add server side verification:

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

But when I look at that page, I get a description of some of the methods, but not instructions on what exactly I write into my view. What exactly do I write onto my view to call on google's verification?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you reference Recaptcha in your controller and then validate on the post

```
@using Recaptcha; // goes in your controller
```

This is an example of how to validate server-side

```
[HttpPost]
[RecaptchaControlMvc.CaptchaValidator]
public ActionResult ForgotPassword(CheckUsernameViewModel model, bool captchaValid, string captchaErrorMessage) {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
        if(captchaValid) {
            // do stuff
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError("", captchaErrorMessage);
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

For all the info, see my posted answer here for the walkthrough to implement correctly.

[How to implement Google reCaptcha in an MVC3 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740402/how-to-implement-google-recaptcha-in-an-mvc3-application/9740583#9740583)

Answer (score 0):

You could use ASP.NET Web Helpers Library. It contains methods that render ReCaptcha, as well as other common widgets. Here's a [link](http://nuget.org/packages/microsoft-web-helpers) to NuGet package.